# Convert strings to opening and closing tags (XML)

Tags: xml, tags, dokuwiki

I'm trying to convert a text file (from Dokuwiki) to XML for further processing. For this I need to convert some special formatting strings to opening and closing tags. 
E.g.: Headlines are marked by "`===`" (`"=== Headline of article ==="`). But I cannot simply replace `"==="` with "`<head>`" since I need the second `"==="` to be "`</head>`" (closing tag). I hope you got what I mean. I have to replace the same string with two different strings depending on the previous one. The program should be written in Python but I actually only need the algorithm...

Thanks

Comment: What about letting the Dokuwiki's parser do the job? In python you could for example use urllib to retrieve the xhtml document. Would it fit your need?

Comment: No it doesn't. But I found a suitable solution on my own: http://pastebin.com/pFGV15sZ
It won't work recursivly but that isn't important for me.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression time:
To replace the first set of `"==="`, use the "^" anchor: `r/^=== /\<head\>/`
To replace the second `"==="`, use the "$" anchor: `r/ ===$/\<\\head\>/`

Comment: After removing the leading "===", you don't really need special methods to select the remaining ones, so could just use the string "===" to match them.